# Flutter - Disable all click events while animation is running

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

There's a `AnimatedSwitcher` in my view which animates the page transition. I want to disable all click events while transition animation is running. Here's what I've tried:

```
class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  int pageIndex = 1;
  bool disableClicks = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AbsorbPointer(
      absorbing: disableClicks,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: AnimatedSwitcher(
          duration: 500.milliseconds,
          child: pageIndex == 0
              ? Container(color: Colors.red, key: UniqueKey())
              : pageIndex == 1
              ? Container(color: Colors.blue, key: UniqueKey())
              : Container(color: Colors.green, key: UniqueKey()),
          transitionBuilder: (child, animation) {
            animation.addStatusListener((status) {
              switch (status) {
                case AnimationStatus.forward:
                case AnimationStatus.reverse:
                  if (mounted && !disableClicks)
                    setState(() {
                      disableClicks = true;
                    });
                  break;
                case AnimationStatus.dismissed:
                case AnimationStatus.completed:
                  if (mounted && disableClicks)
                    setState(() {
                      disableClicks = false;
                    });
                  break;
              }
            });
            return FadeTransition(child: child, opacity: animation);
          },
        ),
        
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But apparently I'm using `setState` while page is building and Flutter is throwing Exception:

`setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.`

What is the proper way to achieve this?

Comment: what are you using for changing the page ?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I'm using `BottomNavigationBar`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try `ValueNotifier` and `ValueListenableBuilder()`.

```
class TwoCents extends StatelessWidget {

  final ValueListenable<bool> disableClicks;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableListener(
      valueListenable: disableClicks,
      onChange: (value) {
        //  do something
      },
      child: ThreeCents(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the two cents. How do I use them? Can you show me the code example?